# How to expose raw SATA disks in KVM guest

Tags: centos7, kvm-virtualization, storage, fedora, sata

I have a CentOS 7.3 64-bit host OS and KVM version (qemu-kvm-1.5.3-126.el7.x86_64) and need to run Fedora Core 13 (32-bit) as guest OS. I have recent hardware which has some SATA and IDE disks attached to it.

I configured it to expose the raw SATA disks (config is as below), but the guest OS lists them as SCSI whereas I would expect it to show up as SATA.

Just to check if this is an issue with KVM I installed CentOS 7.3 as a guest OS (that is same host and guest OS), and the SATA disk lists as ATA (is this your expected behavior and correct? you need to confirm this).

Just to see if anything changes if I upgrade KVM, on another machine (where I don't have SATA disk) I upgraded KVM to centos-release-qemu-evm KVM  qemu-kvm-ev-2.12.0-18.el7_6.1.1 (with CentOS 7.6) and created a file based SATA disk - this also shows up as SCSI in Fedora 13 (32-bit) guest OS.

How do we get to expose a SATA disk as SATA in the guest OS Fedora 13 (32-bit) ?  Also we have some IDE disks and would like to expose them as IDE in the Fedora 13 guest, how can we go about it ?

Appreciate all help.

configuration:

```xml
 <disk type='block' device='disk'\>

      <driver name='SATA' type='raw' cache='none'/>

      <source dev='/dev/sde2'/\>

      <target dev='sde' bus='SATA'/\>

</disk\>
```

Comment: Exactly what do you mean when you say that "the guest OS lists them as SCSI"? Please show us exactly what you saw.

Comment: In both host and guest I ran "udevadm info --query=property  --name=/dev/sde" command. The command output in host showing  as " ID_PATH=pci-0000:02:00.0-sas-0x5fae190000009883-lun-0
, ID_SAS_PATH=pci-0000:02:00.0-sas-exp0x5fae1900000098bf-phy3-lun" and in guest as "ID_SCSI_COMPAT=SATA_QEMU_HARDDISK_QM00005, ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:09.0-scsi-0:0:0:0".  Even in guest I have udevrule which didn't recognises the disk as SATA/SAS.

Comment: Hmm. Is something broken? Fedora 13 is many years past end of life, so you probably won't be able to get any support anyway.